# Measuring execution time in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I had time measuring pretty much [figured out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21995693/2567683) when I ended up using this structure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

template<typename TimeT = std::chrono::milliseconds>
struct measure
{
    template<typename F>
    static typename TimeT::rep execution(F const &func)
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        func();
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast< TimeT>(
            std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
        return duration.count();
    }
};
```

a use case would be

```
struct functor
{
    int state;
    functor(int state) : state(state) {}
    void operator()() const
    {
        std::cout << "In functor run for ";
    }
};

void func()
{
    std::cout << "In function, run for " << std::endl;
}

void func(int arg) {}

int main()
{
    int dummy(1);

    std::cout << measure<>::execution( [&]() {  
        func(dummy);
    }) << std::endl;

    std::cout << measure<>::execution(functor(dummy)) << std::endl;
std::cout << measure<>::execution(func);

    return 0;
}
```

But since I started using my struct in various posts on Stack Exchange sites, I've had remarks and comments about the code (like on `func` being a const ref or not etc).

I'd like a review on the above and your suggestions on how I can approve this code (or leave it alone [at last](https://github.com/picanumber/bureaucrat/blob/master/time_lapse.h)).

Comment: Your class won't work with functions which need paramaters. Is it supposed to be so?

Comment: It'll work, just call the function throught a lambda

Comment: @ NikosAthanasiou Yes, that's possible. But measurements will be out of phase, since you are measuring the other function's execution time too.

Comment: @black Lambda functions are always inlined, so the code is called in place. Besides, for any measurement to take place, a single function call (which as stated before will be inlined) is not a factor.

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou As you prefer. But consider that it is neither logical nor expected to work that way.

Comment: @black OK I'll have to give you credit after all. I wouldn't consider it a problem, but after seeing Loki's answer, I have to admit it has a more natural feel. So +1 to your initial comment

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou: One thing to keep in mind is that for each function you measure it this way, you'll get a separate chunk of code instantiated, so using it many places in the same program could lead to some degree of code bloat which may also somewhat interfere with the timing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Extend your timer function so it can take all the parameters needed by `func()`
2. Don bother to pass `func` by const reference.

#### What I would have done

```
template<typename TimeT = std::chrono::milliseconds>
struct measure
{
    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    static typename TimeT::rep execution(F func, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

        // Now call the function with all the parameters you need.
        func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast< TimeT>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);

        return duration.count();
    }
};
```

Comment: +1 . Those variadic templates solve so many problems! Would you recommend a source where I can learn more ? (please don't say the Standard)

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou: This person seems to know what he is talking about. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/39083/iavr read some of his answers

Comment: Quick question. Why can't it [compile](http://ideone.com/OeERav) the original example ? I'm supposing due to the overloads func, but can I have any thoughts on that?

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou: Its because you have two functions named `func()`. It does not know which one you mean when you go `measure<>::execution(func);` (it could be either). You can either name the functions differently or you can be specific when specifying them by providing the functions type `measure<>::execution<void()>(func);`.

Comment: I updated the [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21995693/2567683) with an improvement : We can use a universal reference for the `func` provided that we [forward the function call](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31253334/2567683)

Comment: Isn't this kind of overkill, seeing how we could just wrap the function call in a lambda and time that?

Comment: @einpoklum I have no idea what you are talking about. Write an answer and get votes on it.

Comment: Sorry for the late question, but - why return the count rather than the duration? I know OP did that but is that really a good idea?

Answer (score 10):

It seems a bit of a bother to approach it as a function template when it seems to me that it's more like an object.  For that reason, here's an alternative that might be a little more natural to use:

```
template<typename TimeT = std::chrono::microseconds, 
    typename ClockT=std::chrono::high_resolution_clock,
    typename DurationT=double>
class Stopwatch
{
private:
    std::chrono::time_point<ClockT> _start, _end;
public:
    Stopwatch() { start(); }
    void start() { _start = _end = ClockT::now(); }
    DurationT stop() { _end = ClockT::now(); return elapsed();}
    DurationT elapsed() { 
        auto delta = std::chrono::duration_cast<TimeT>(_end-_start);
        return delta.count(); 
    }
};
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Stopwatch<> sw;
functionToBeTimed(arg1, arg2);
sw.stop();
std::cout << "functionToBeTimed took " << sw.elapsed() << " microseconds\n";
```

Comment: Disagree with `more natural`. But this has the advantage you can time multiple function calls.

Comment: You can also time things that are not functions.

Comment: I would be careful about timing things that are not functions because of optimizations that the compiler is allowed to do. I am not sure about the sequencing requirements and the observable behavior understanding of such a program. With a function call the compiler is not allowed to move statements across the call point (they are sequenced before or after the call).

Comment: +1. I find this quite natural. I usually write my own timer object like that, with members called `tic()`, `toc()` (instead of `start()`, `stop()`), following the [matlab style](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html). Plus `tac()`, which measures elapsed time without stopping the timer. But all this is complementary rather than competitive to the proposed `measure()` function template (including parameters). Why not have all in a timer object?

Comment: @iavr: good point about them being complementary mechanisms.  Also, while I never liked the overly cute matlab names, I'll point out that `stop()` isn't an entirely accurate name and actually functions more like `toc()` in that neither `stop()` nor `toc()` actually stop the timer.

Comment: @LokiAstari i would guess that if compiler would not reorder instructions around calls to `ClockT:now()`. It would make sense for that function's implementation to have some kind of memory barrier or similar primitive to avoid reordering

Answer (score 3):

You should use `std::chrono::steady_clock` instead of `std::chrono::system_clock`. This is because `system_clock` may get adjusted every now and then (e.g. it may rewind back a bit, or jump forward more than the actual elapsed time in order to keep in sync with the wall/world clock), whereas steady_clock is a monotonic clock that is never adjusted. Therefore, `steady_clock` is better suited for what you're doing.

P.S. If you need to know how much CPU-time your function is actually taking, even `steady_clock` may not be ideal, as it will only measure the duration from the time your function is called, to the time it returns. This may not necessarily be equal to the amount of CPU-time the function took, as other processes and threads can interrupt your function and result in significantly longer execution times. If you want to isolate the effects of other system activities, you should google OS/platform-specific alternatives for getting the thread execution time or look up the [chrono functions in Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/chrono.html) (look for the `process_...cpu_clock` and `thread_clock` classes).

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much more to improve after the code has begun to accept function parameters.

These are some details, you could freely ignore them:

- Class names should begin with an uppercase letter

  ```
  struct Measure
  ```
- You don't need the `duration` variable; just do:

  ```
  return std::chrono::duration_cast< TimeT>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
  ```

Comment: I agree that it is a good idea to have type names begin with Upper case letters (seems to be a common practice). But `should` is a bit strong.

Comment: Disagree on removing the variable `duration`. The compiler will remove all wasted space so the code will still be optimal (ie no different than your version) with the variable. But it helps in reading the code (and code is for the human to read so make it easy on us humans and leave the variables in to make it easier to read). Also when debugging it makes it easier to check the result when you have it stored in a variable.

Comment: I kind of disagree on both: `duration` removal for the same reason as Loki, class name capitalization because you are free to choose your own code style (actually standard library classes are not capitalized, aren't they?)