# Computing function time in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, benchmarking

I used the `std::chrono` library for computing the timing of a function and need some review on it.

Here is the code:

```
namespace gstd
{

#ifdef GTIME
    inline namespace gtime
    {
        template<typename type, typename period>
        using duration = std::chrono::duration<type, period>;
        std::function<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>( )>current_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;

        template<typename RetType>
        std::optional<double> getFunctionTime(std::function<RetType(void)>function) {
            try {    
                auto start_time = current_time( );
                function( );
                auto end_time = current_time( );
                duration<double, std::milli> dur = end_time - start_time;
                return dur.count( );
            }
            catch ( ... ) {
                return {};    
            }
        }
        template <typename RetType, typename arg>
        std::optional<double> getFunctionTime1(std::function<RetType(arg)> function, arg value) {
            try {
                auto start_time = current_time( );
                function(value);
                auto end_time = current_time( );
                duration<double, std::milli> dur = end_time - start_time;
                return dur.count( );
            }
            catch ( ... ) {
                return {};
            }
        }
        template<typename RetType, typename arg1, typename arg2>
        std::optional<double> getFunction2(std::function<RetType(arg1, arg2)>function, arg1 firstparam, arg2 secondparam) {
            try {                   
                auto start_time = current_time( );
                function(firstparam, secondparam);
                auto end_time = current_time( );
                duration<double, std::milli> dur = end_time - start_time;
                return dur.count( );
            }
            catch ( ... ) {
                return {};
            }
        }
    }

#endif // GTIME    
}
```

This is the code in the header file. Now how i am using it is here:

```
#define GTIME

#include "GStandard.h"
#include <iostream>

int number_crunching( ) {
    int sum { 0 };
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++ )
        sum += 1;
    return sum;
}
int multiplier(int number) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++ ) {
        number *= ( i + 1 );    
    }
    return number;
}
int sum( int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
int main( ) {
    auto ftime = gstd::getFunctionTime<int>(number_crunching);
    auto f1time = gstd::getFunctionTime1<int, int>(multiplier, 5);
    auto f2time = gstd::getFunction2<int, int,  int>(sum, 4, 5);

    std::cout << ftime.value( ) << '\n';
    std::cout << f1time.value( ) << '\n';
    std::cout << f2time.value( ) << '\n';

    std::cin.get( );
    return 0;
}
```

Some suggestions were previously made on making it variadic but I am not doing it so that the students at my college can make improvement to this code. I am looking forward to removing the try catch block and if there are any more changes that you guys could suggest that would be very nice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Be more generic

As I've suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50655478/1593077), you should not force the use of an `std::function`. Instead, take any type of callable and either a fixed or an unlimited number of arguments, using `std::invoke` inside your implementation.

More importantly, you really don't need multiple functions for a different number of arguments; use variadic templates, e.g. have a signature such as:

```
template< class F, class... Args>
std::optional<double> getFunctionTime(F&& f, Args&&... args) noexcept;
```

(ignoring any other potential changes)

This will make it easier for you to invoke, too:

```
auto ftime = gstd::getFunctionTime(number_crunching);
auto f1time = gstd::getFunctionTime(multiplier, 5);
auto f2time = gstd::getFunctionTime(sum, 4, 5);
```

Alternatively, you could *only* accept 0-argument runnables, in which case you simply pass lambdas:

```
auto f1time = gstd::getFunctionTime([]() { return multiplier(5); });
```

#### Return a `chrono::duration`

Don't convert your duration to a plain numeric value - keep the more specific type.

#### Use integral values for durations

Why use a floating-point value in the duration? Stick with integral values unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.

#### Consider changing the name

I'd use `time_an_invocation` or `time_invocation` but I guess that's a matter of taste.

#### Consider leaving it to the caller to handle exceptions

You're forcing a certain behavior w.r.t. exceptions. I'd consider simply not handling them, so that timing the invocation of a function that throws an exception, throws an exception. That would simplify your code and avoid a  dependence on `std::optional`, which the caller might not be interested in. Remember the caller has to have additional code to handle the empty-optional case anyway.

#### Consider using a stopwatch class instead

In a [related question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48872), @Edward [suggests](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/48884/64513) keeping the invocation and the time measurement separate, using a "stop-watch" class. That might not be "better" but it's certainly worth considering.